# Mysql error shows #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I tried to use order by in following query but error shows #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

```
UPDATE products 
JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0 ) r 
SET `sort_order`=@rank:=@rank+1 
WHERE `prd_status`=1 AND `prd_popular`=1 AND `prd_booked`=0 AND `prd_sold`=1 AND `prd_rd_mini`=0
ORDER BY `prd_price`DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no **ORDER BY** in multi table update
see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/

use query like this:

```
SELECT @rank:=0;  
UPDATE products p
SET p.`sort_order`=@rank:=@rank+1 
WHERE p.`prd_status`=1 ;AND p.`prd_popular`=1 AND p.`prd_booked`=0 AND p.`prd_sold`=1 AND p.`prd_rd_mini`=0
ORDER BY p.`prd_price` DESC;
```

Comment: i have change my answer

Comment: Following MYSQL Query Taking Long Time To Execute How to reduce execution time any solution? The table contains more than 1000 records I am trying to update sort order (prd_sort_order) based on price (prd_price) in a product table

SELECT @rank:=0;  
UPDATE rana_products_demo p
SET p.`sort_order`=@rank:=@rank+1 
WHERE p.`prd_booking_status`=1 AND p.`prd_status`=1 
ORDER BY p.`prd_price` DESC;

Comment: @Mentalist - Do you have the correct indexes. pls show us the executionplan **EXPLAIN yourquery**